# Add Typescript Typing to function prototype in Decorator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a problem on how to add typings into function prototype in Decorators. What I'm trying to archive in Component Class is, I would like to unsubscribe rxjs when this component run `ngOnDestroy`. It's already working but it lacks of typings.

Here my code

```
// Component 
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { debounceTime, filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UnsubscribeComponent } from '@app/helper/unsubsribe-component.helper';

@UnsubscribeComponent()
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-filter',
  templateUrl: './modal-filter.component.html',
})
export class ModalFilterComponent implements OnInit {

  public formFilter: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.formFilter = this.formBuilder.group({
      'startDate': [null, Validators.required],
      'endDate': [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.formFilter.valueChanges.pipe(
      // @ts-ignore  <- If i add this the warning will gone but i dont want to add this every rxjs later.
      this.unsubsribeOnDestroy,   // <- Error "Property of unsubsribeOnDestroy is not exist on type ModalFilterComponent"
      debounceTime(200),
      filter(_ => this.formFilter.valid),
    ).subscribe();
  }

}
```

Here my Decorator function `UnsubscribeComponent`

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

export function UnsubscribeComponent(): ClassDecorator {
  const destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  return function (componentClass: any) {
    const destroyHook = componentClass.prototype['ngOnDestroy'];

    componentClass.prototype['unsubsribeOnDestroy'] = (source: Observable<any>): Observable<any> =>
        source.pipe(takeUntil(destroyed$));

    componentClass.prototype['ngOnDestroy'] = () => {
      destroyed$.next(true);
      destroyed$.complete();

      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
      destroyHook && destroyHook();
    };
  };
}
```

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Answer (score 0):

As per [the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) yurzui linked, TypeScript doesn't support class decorators that change the type of a class.  I'd suggest putting the `UnsubscribeComponent` logic in a base class that you can extend from `ModalFilterComponent` instead of a decorator.  If that becomes a problem because you want your components to extend another class, then you could move the unsubscribe logic to a [mix-in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-mix-in-classes) that you could apply to any desired base class before extending it in your component.

Comment: Thank you Matt McCutchen, now i understand a bit what yurzui link is. Anyway as far as I understand the mix-in approach is still using extend keyword, which I would like to avoid, because later I have to type alot of code `constructor() { super() } `, `extends ...`. to every componenet class. 

Thank you.

Comment: The problem may not be as bad as you think.  If the only code in your constructor would be `super();`, you can leave the constructor out.  Only if you need to define a constructor for another reason, then you have to add `super();` to it.  The `extends` clause doesn't seem much worse than the decorator call to me.